# How to add a custom javascript in a Magento extension

Tags: javascript, php, xml, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to add a javascript to all Magento pages inside tag `<head>`. I have a file called `example.xml` in this folders tree (I've made a configuration on `etc/config.xml` to use a custom .xml file like `example.xml`):

```
--design
----frontend
------base
--------default
----------layout
------------example.xml
```

I'm using two approaches to do this. The first one is (NOT WORKING):

```
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>folder/myjavascript.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

The second one is (WORKING only for checkout page):

```
<layout>
    <example_handle>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>folder/myjavascript.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </example_handle>

    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <update handle="example_handle"/>
    </checkout_onepage_index>

    <onepagecheckout_index_index>
        <update handle="example_handle"/>
    </onepagecheckout_index_index>

    <opc_index_index>
        <update handle="example_handle"/>
    </opc_index_index>

    <aw_onestepcheckout_index_index>
        <update handle="example_handle"/>
    </aw_onestepcheckout_index_index>
</layout>
```

My javascript has a snippet where I need to get a custom variable from Magento (in php I use `getConfigData('api_key')`). So, my second question is: Is it possible to get this value directly from javascript or I need to do this with php?

```
var _api_key = ?`getConfigData('api_key')`?;
```

Comment: Please make clear within your question which of the many mehtods to achieve that you have followed, provide reference to the Magento homepage that is documenting the method you follow, explain what you expected to happen and what happened instead. Also please make clear why existing Q&A material on site didn't work for you and why while providing a reference to it.

Comment: Alao please keep your questions apart. Stackoverflow doesn't work well asking two or more questions within the same question post. Instead keep the questions apart and ask as isolated as possible to create the greatest value for this Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to execute php code then need call phtml
This call phtml file as reference block of head.

```
<example_handle>
    <reference name="head">
       <block type="core/template" template="page/myjavascript.phtml" name="myjavascript" />
    </reference>
</example_handle>
```

then on phtml(`app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_TEMPATE/template/page/myjavascrpt.phtml`)  write php code:  and put all code of myjavascript.js to this phtml.

then call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('myjavascript');?>` in `head.phtml`